# OutOfMemoryError when rendering ImageButtons

Tags: java, android

I got an out of memory error and am not exactly sure how to handle it. I would appreciate any help! I think the problem lies with loading too many images, but how can I avoid that? I think I'm only loading a total of 15 cards + background

```
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime: Process: caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator, PID: 6063
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 11287248 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 5MB until OOM
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:170)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:115)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1215)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1124)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2630)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:771)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator.Main.setSuit(Main.java:193)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator.Main.onClick(Main.java:142)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
01-14 10:18:25.530 6063-6063/caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

code:

```
package caffeinereliantstudentstudios.pokerprobabilitycalculator;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends FragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    //declaring variables
    private ImageView s1, s2;
    private Button back, next;
    private ImageButton[] ib = new ImageButton[13], suit = new ImageButton[4];
    private int[] own_c, own_c_id, own_suit, card_id;
    private int temp_suit, no_c = -1, spade = 0, heart = 1, club = 2, diamond = 3;
    private TextView intro;
    private boolean suit_select;
    private HorizontalScrollView hscroll;
    private LinearLayout cards;
    private Drawable d;
    private String path;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //set up scroller for cards
    hscroll = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hscroll);
    hscroll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //assigning cards
    ib[0] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.c1);
    ib[1] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.c2);
    ib[2] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.c3);
    ib[3] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.c4);
    ib[4] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.c5);
    ib[5] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.c6);
    ib[6] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.c7);
    ib[7] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.c8);
    ib[8] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.c9);
    ib[9] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.c10);
    ib[10] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cj);
    ib[11] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cq);
    ib[12] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ck);

    //set up suits selection
    cards = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cards);
    suit[0] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.spade);
    suit[1] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.heart);
    suit[2] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.club);
    suit[3] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.diamond);

    //set up card listeners
    for(int i = 0; i < ib.length; i++){
        ib[i].setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < suit.length; i++){
        suit[i].setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    //set up back and next buttons
    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_but);
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_but);
    //set on click listener
    back.setOnClickListener(this);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);
    //make it invisible to start with
    back.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    next.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    //we have no cards yet
    own_c = new int[2];
    own_c[0] = no_c;
    own_c[1] = no_c;
    own_c_id = new int[2];
    own_suit = new int[2];

    //selected cards on screen 1
    s1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.s1);
    s2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.s2);
    //set to invisible
    s1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    s2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    //directions
    intro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.intro);

    //selecting suits first
    suit_select = true;

    //setting up card ids
    card_id = cardIdSetup();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    if(v.getId() == back.getId()){
        //reset card data
        own_c[0] = no_c;
        own_c[1] = no_c;
        own_suit[0] = no_c;
        own_suit[1] = no_c;
        //make the selected cards disappear
        s1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        s2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //reveal proper selection menu
        hscroll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        cards.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        intro.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //remove buttons
        next.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        back.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else if(v.getId() == next.getId()){
        //moving to next activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PublicCard.class);
        //pass data
        intent.putExtra("own_c", own_c);
        intent.putExtra("own_c_id", own_c_id);
        intent.putExtra("own_suit", own_suit);
        //start activity
        startActivity(intent);
        //remove transition
        overridePendingTransition(0,0);
    }else if(suit_select){//if they haven't selected a suit yet
        for(int i = 0; i < suit.length; i++){//check which suit they want
            if(v.getId() == suit[i].getId()){
                temp_suit = i;
                suit_select = false;//make the next selection be for cards
                hscroll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//make card section screen visible
                //show only those that weren't already selected
                revealNotSelected(temp_suit, own_suit, own_c);
                //remove suit selection
                cards.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //set drawable of cards for proper suit
                setSuit(temp_suit);
            }
        }
    }else{//time for selecting the card
        for(int i = 0; i < ib.length; i++){
            if(v.getId() == ib[i].getId()){
                d = ib[i].getBackground();//get background
                if(own_c[1] == -1){//set card to right
                    own_c[1] = i;
                    own_suit[1] = temp_suit;
                    own_c_id[1] = v.getId();
                    s2.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
                    s2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ib[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else if(own_c[0] == -1){//set card to left
                    own_c[0] = i;
                    own_suit[0] = temp_suit;
                    own_c_id[0] = v.getId();
                    s1.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
                    s1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                //once we know which card they want, we can
                //go back to the suit selection screen.
                //loop will go through quickly
                hscroll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                suit_select = true;
                cards.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
    //ensure proper buttons are shown
    if(own_c[0] != no_c && own_c[1] != no_c){
        next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        intro.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
        next.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        intro.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if(own_c[0] != own_c[1]){
        back.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        back.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

private void setSuit(int suit){
    int suit_num = suit * 13;
    int temp;
    for(int index = 0; index < this.ib.length; index++) {
        temp = suit_num + index;
            this.ib[index].setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(card_id[temp]));
    }
}

private int[] cardIdSetup(){
    int[] temp = new int[52];
    temp[0] = R.drawable.c0;
    temp[1] = R.drawable.c1;
    temp[2] = R.drawable.c2;
    temp[3] = R.drawable.c3;
    temp[4] = R.drawable.c4;
    temp[5] = R.drawable.c5;
    temp[6] = R.drawable.c6;
    temp[7] = R.drawable.c7;
    temp[8] = R.drawable.c8;
    temp[9] = R.drawable.c9;
    temp[10] = R.drawable.c10;
    temp[11] = R.drawable.c11;
    temp[12] = R.drawable.c12;
    temp[13] = R.drawable.c13;
    temp[14] = R.drawable.c14;
    temp[15] = R.drawable.c15;
    temp[16] = R.drawable.c16;
    temp[17] = R.drawable.c17;
    temp[18] = R.drawable.c18;
    temp[19] = R.drawable.c19;
    temp[20] = R.drawable.c20;
    temp[21] = R.drawable.c21;
    temp[22] = R.drawable.c22;
    temp[23] = R.drawable.c23;
    temp[24] = R.drawable.c24;
    temp[25] = R.drawable.c25;
    temp[26] = R.drawable.c26;
    temp[27] = R.drawable.c27;
    temp[28] = R.drawable.c28;
    temp[29] = R.drawable.c29;
    temp[30] = R.drawable.c30;
    temp[31] = R.drawable.c31;
    temp[32] = R.drawable.c32;
    temp[33] = R.drawable.c33;
    temp[34] = R.drawable.c34;
    temp[35] = R.drawable.c35;
    temp[36] = R.drawable.c36;
    temp[37] = R.drawable.c37;
    temp[38] = R.drawable.c38;
    temp[39] = R.drawable.c39;
    temp[40] = R.drawable.c40;
    temp[41] = R.drawable.c41;
    temp[42] = R.drawable.c42;
    temp[43] = R.drawable.c43;
    temp[44] = R.drawable.c44;
    temp[45] = R.drawable.c45;
    temp[46] = R.drawable.c46;
    temp[47] = R.drawable.c47;
    temp[48] = R.drawable.c48;
    temp[49] = R.drawable.c49;
    temp[50] = R.drawable.c50;
    temp[51] = R.drawable.c51;
    return temp;
}

private void revealNotSelected(int suit, int[] own_suits, int[] own_cards){
    for(int j = 0; j < this.ib.length; j++) {
        this.ib[j].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        for (int k = 0; k < own_suits.length; k++) {
            if (suit == own_suits[k] && own_cards[k] == j) {
                this.ib[j].setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the app is a poker probability calculator. The main class contains code for the user to select cards in his currently in his hands, but first selecting which suit the card is, then selecting the card (to avoid rendering 52 cards at the same time). Repeat for the second card, and then you have the option to move on to the second screen, where you choose the cards dealt.
The part where it crashes is right after I selected my suit for the first card. At this point, only the background and 4 cards should be rendered. After pressing the suit, the 4 cards disappear, and 13 cards from that suit are rendered and displayed. A reset selection button also appears now (and text changes to guide the user to select the card).
Thank you!

Comment: How big are your images?

Comment: but width and heigth not on disk ... also it is important for which dpi ..

Comment: Don't use large images.

Comment: @Jamie 712x992 for the lowest resolution and 3796x5289 for the highest dpi

Comment: @Selvin I'm using a nexus 10 for testing. I have included all dpi's files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use BitmapFactory.options to load in an image at a lower resolution or your going to get oom error

```
private void setSuit(int suit){
    int suit_num = suit * 13;
    int temp;
    for(int index = 0; index < this.ib.length; index++) {
        temp = suit_num + index;
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource (getResources(), card_id[temp],options)                                         
                options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options,100,100);//100 and 100 whatever you want as scale
                    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),card_id[temp],options);
           BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), yourSelectedImage)
            this.ib[index].setBackgroundDrawable(ob);
    }
}
```

helper method

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
    }
```

Comment: thank you! however it doesn't seem like you used the helper method. What could it be used for?

Comment: sorry it was in there but far to the right and you couldn't see it, I edited the answer so it is visible